# java11 soap wsdl2java :how to create a class from wsdl file in java

Tags: maven, soap, pom.xml, java-11, wsdl2java

I am creating webservice in soap using java11 and wsdl file has been created then after that i tried to generate java class from wsdl file but an error occured. In java11 wsimport and wsgen has been removed so I have added appropriate dependency for that in pom.xml file. If there is any error or alternate solution for this kindly mention that I will be sharing the screenshot and pom.xml below.

[i dont know what error is this javax/jws/soap/SOAPBinding$Style kindly check this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSfgT.png)

this is the pom.xml file I have used

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      
    <packaging>war</packaging>
      
    <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      
    <groupId>com.inno.innowebservices</groupId>
      
    <artifactId>InnoWebservices1</artifactId>
      
    <properties>
            
        <appengine.maven.plugin.version>2.4.0</appengine.maven.plugin.version>
            
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
            
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
            
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
            
        <maven.compiler.showDeprecation>true</maven.compiler.showDeprecation>
          
    </properties>
      
    <dependencyManagement>
            
        <dependencies>
                  
            <dependency>
                        
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                        
                <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
                        
                <version>15.0.0</version>
                        
                <type>pom</type>
                        
                <scope>import</scope>
                      
            </dependency>
                
        </dependencies>
          
    </dependencyManagement>
      
    <dependencies>
            
        <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->
            
        <dependency>
                  
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                  
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                  
            <version>3.1.0</version>
                  
            <scope>provided</scope>
                
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.metro</groupId>
            <artifactId>webservices-rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>

       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
         </dependency>
            
        <dependency>
                  
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                  
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
                  
            <version>2.3.1</version>
                  
            <scope>provided</scope>
                
        </dependency>
            
        <dependency>
                  
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
                  
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                  
            <version>1.2</version>
                
        </dependency>
            
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.83</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.endpoints</groupId>
            <artifactId>endpoints-framework</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.objectify</groupId>
            <artifactId>objectify</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Test Dependencies -->
            
        <dependency>
                  
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
                  
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                  
            <version>4.12</version>
                  
            <scope>test</scope>
                
        </dependency>
          
    </dependencies>
      
    <build>
            
        <!-- for hot reload of the web application-->
            
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
            
        <plugins>
                  
            <plugin>
                        
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                        
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        
                <version>${appengine.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                      
            </plugin>
                  
      
            <plugin>
                        
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                        
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                        
                <executions>
                              
                    <execution>
                                    
                        <id>enforce-maven</id>
                                    
                        <goals>
                                          
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                                        
                        </goals>
                                    
                        <configuration>
                                          
                            <rules>
                                                
                                <!-- appengine-maven-plugin requires Maven 3.5.0 or later -->
                                                
                                <requireMavenVersion>
                                                      
                                    <version>3.5.0</version>
                                                    
                                </requireMavenVersion>
                                              
                            </rules>
                                        
                        </configuration>
                                  
                    </execution>
                            
                </executions>
                      
            </plugin>
                
        </plugins>
          
    </build>
    
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Java 11. Long time was looking for solution to create Java classes from WSDL using wsdl2java. And finally managed to do this. There is no option to attach zip file to message so I will discribe.

I created 2 bat files. With next content

1. **wsdl2java.bat**

`"JDK_PATH\bin\java.exe" -cp -cp axis-1.4.jar;commons-logging-1.2.jar;commons-discovery-0.5.jar;javax.xml.rpc-api-1.1.2.jar;javax.xml.soap-api-1.4.0.jar;axis-wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar;activation-1.1.1.jar;javax.mail-api-1.6.2.jar org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java %*`

2. **runMe.bat**

`wsdl2java -p package.name.to.save Filename.wsdl`

You need to download all this jar files from https://mvnrepository.com

Answer (score 0):

jaxws-maven-plugin newer version can be used to generated classes from wsdl with Java 11. Following plugin conf may be helpful - tested and working fine:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-java-sources</id>
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsimport</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <extension>true</extension>
                            <wsdlFiles>
                                <wsdlFile>${basedir}/src/wsdl/yourservice.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                            </wsdlFiles>
                            <wsdlLocation>/src/wsdl/yourservice.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
                        <version>1.3.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.jws</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javax.jws-api</artifactId>
                        <version>1.1</version>
                    </dependency>                   
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```